# Mark Of The Web and XML+XSL

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, mark-of-the-web

Is it possible to use Mark of the Web in XML file which is parsed by a local XSL file?

When I insert MOTW mark:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

i get following message:
Access is Denied. Error Processing Resource.

---

Ok, I see that I was trying to do it wrong - I wanted to insert this comment into XML.

I have three files: XML with data, XSL to transform the data into html, and JS file with JavaScript functions. As you said, I want to get rid of the Internet Explorer orange bar.

Putting everything on IIS or Apache is good way, but I want to open these files localy.

I tried to insert xml:comment tag, but nothing happened (the bar is still showing).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it - no. MOTW here forces the "Internet" Zone upon the whole process, so accessing local resources is off limits. The error message you get expresses this fact.

If *testing* your page is what you try to do, you will have to fetch it from a web server, alongside with the XSL. The IIS on your machine, accessed through "http:/localhost/..." would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried several variations of <xsl:comment> saved from url=(0014)about:internet </xsl:comment>. The MOTW just doesn't work for pages generated through XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the MOTW (Mark of the web) will only help you when loading a local page with JavaScript to not see the silly yellow warning bar. (AFAIK)

If this is your intention, can you not just use:

```
<xsl:comment> saved from url=(0014)about:internet </xsl:comment>
```

as the output just before your DOCTYPE / html tag.